# How to combine multiple Select queries in a single one MySql

Tags: mysql

In a webpage I want to display several tables with information.

To do that, at the moment I do

```
SELECT * FROM tableONE WHERE field LIKE 'criteria'
```

then I process the result in a foreach loop. Then I do another query to the next table and process it again

```
SELECT * FROM tableTWO WHERE field LIKE 'criteria'

.... 
SELECT * FROM tableTWENTY WHERE field LIKE 'criteria'
```

I've the feeling that making 20 connections with the database is suboptimal and I could make a single query and in the foreach loop put each result in the appropriate table. The issues I found to do it are:

- There is no related column amongst them, so **I can not do a JOIN ON.**
- If I do a cartesian join I get many redundant rows
- **I can not use UNION** because the columns on each table are different.

What is the most efficient way to do this?
Thanks

**I've tried JOIN, UNION and separating the tables with comas (cartesian join)**, but they don't give the expected result

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to optimize a non-issue. You are not doing 20 connections, just 20 round trips. If they are logically different datasets, then keep them as their separate queries. Adding more specific examples to your question _may_ result in a different conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just use UNION Clause

```
SELECT field1, field2, filed3 FROM table1

UNION

SELECT field1, NULL as filed2, field4 as filed3 FROM table2
;
```

Beware that

- Every `SELECT` statement within `UNION` must have the same number of columns
- The columns must also have similar data types

Comment: This fails because tables have different number of columns
#1222 - El comando SELECT usado tiene diferente número de columnas

Comment: @AlfonsoBueno just list them in your queries. If you don't have a corresponding column you can go with `SELECT NULL as missing_column`

Comment: `NULL as missing_column` looks like a good workaround

Comment: UNIONing disparate result sets to reduce round trips to the db server is a bad idea!

Comment: @nnichols what is the right thing to do in this case? Going 20 times to the database?

Comment: @AlfonsoBueno Yes, running 20 queries is no big deal. As with any queries, the underlying tables should be appropriately indexed but other than that just crack on. Artificially UNIONing disparate datasets will be a maintenance disaster and likely have unforeseen side effects.